# How to fit one div to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fit my `div` (fade and morph-spinner) to base `div` (name-container). How can I do it? Here is my code on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyy8egb0/7

I mean I want to size `fade` and `morph-spinner` in accordance with size of `name-container`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, there are a couple of very bad things in your fiddle, starting with this:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, just... don't.

Here's a better version: http://jsfiddle.net/u6nLj532/

As for your question, I suppose you want to do this:

```
$("#fade, #morph-spinner")
    .width($("#name-container").outerWidth())
    .css("left", $("#name-container").offset().left);
```

The thing is, you're trying to reinvent the wheel, as there is a jQuery plugin that does just that. See the demos here: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Here's a version with the plugin, you only need to style it: http://jsfiddle.net/u6nLj532/2/

Comment: But it's not fit for name-container.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, I just set them to the same width. Use the jQuery BlockUI plugin instead.

Comment: I can't find where to add style for font and spinner style (morph-spinner).

Comment: There are several examples on the plugin site. Either add some html inside the `message` option, or tweak the `css` and/or `overlayCSS` option.

Comment: I can't figure out hot to change `cursor:'wait'` to my spinner.

Comment: I added spinner. But now its in the bottom. I mean it isn't tied to `name-container`. Actually I was my question about how to fit one div to another, how to tied them.